# Awesome wm 4 middle align does not work in horizontal layout

Tags: user-interface, lua, scripting, window-managers, awesome-wm

On my previous awesome installation (awesome 3.5) I wrote [**the configurations**](https://github.com/ThePinkPanther/MinimalAwesome/blob/master/toolbar.lua) that do not work the same way in version 4 anymore. I would align a container within horizontal align like this:

```
local center_layout = wibox.layout.fixed.horizontal()
local left_layout = wibox.layout.fixed.horizontal()
local right_layout = wibox.layout.fixed.horizontal()
-- Fill layouts with widgets


local layout = wibox.layout.align.horizontal()

layout:set_left(left_layout)
layout:set_right(right_layout)
layout:set_middle(center_layout)
```

but the center_layout is aligned on the left instead of center like this:

[image]

I also tried replacing the above code with

```
local layout = wibox.widget {
    left_layout  ,
    center_layout ,
    right_layout  ,
    layout  = wibox.layout.align.horizontal
}
```

but it diddin't do any change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `expand` to `outside` for your `align` layout: https://awesomewm.org/doc/api/classes/wibox.layout.align.html#wibox.layout.align.expand

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find an example anywhere but @ulishlachter's answer got me the last mile:

```
s.mywibox3:setup({
  layout = wibox.layout.align.horizontal,
  expand = 'outside',
  nil,
  {
    layout = wibox.layout.fixed.horizontal,
    todowidget,
    space,
    pomowidget,
  },
  nil,
})
```